# Параметры хостинга

Tags: хостинг

Для меня "1200 сек/сутки процессорного времени" и "180 сек/сутки времени sql-запросов" к сожалению ничего не говорит, а это одни из характеристик тарифа хостинга. Хотелось бы узнать, хоть примерно, сколько вышеуказанных ресурсов потребляют среднестатистические сайты или получить какую-нибудь информацию по наведенным характеристикам.

**Заранее спасибо!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну средняя "цена" sql запроса (конечно сильно зависит от качества запроса) - может быть 0,007 сек, а может быть и 0,3 сек (запросы взяты из самописного php сайта, к сожалению популярные cms не приведу). Если во втором случае брать в расчет 180 сек, то это явно не много.

Скорее всего это средняя цифра взятая из статистики хостинга. Полезной эту информацию не назовешь. Я думаю вам стоит задать этот вопрос товарищам из ho.ua

Answer (score 1):

Учтите, пожалуйста, один нюанс: в исходное ПО (MySQL, apache) не включен расчет процессорного времени, лишь можно настроить таймаут, но, я думаю, он к данному вопросу не имеет отношения. Получается, что этими условиями стараются как-то "испугать" клиента с целью того, чтобы он не разбазаривал процессорное время. Взять, к примеру, панель управления ISPmanager. Там есть функция ограничения процессорного времени, которая создает отдельный для пользователя конфигурационный файл (PHP) php.ini и в переменной `max_execution_time` задает это ограничительное значение. Но иногда это ограничение удается обходить вызовом `set_time_limit`(NULL). А уж суммарно подсчитать потраченное процессорное время по-моему трудно и ресурсоемко, так как приходится каждый запрос перехватывать. Короче, выражаясь четко, все это БРЕХНЯ, крутите, как хотите. )))